# Why can't I edit just the regular bootstrap.css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm diving into Bootstrap, and I'm beginning with the simplest example possible. In my HTML file there's only one line regarding style sheet:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the css folder I've deleted all other css files (minified and css map) except bootstrap.css and bootstrap-theme.css - and now the HTML file lookes screwed up.

But when I copy back the minified css in the directory, the HTML renders fine - despite no link to it in the HTML. How is that possible?

Comment: Can't be, no calls for voodoo in the header either :)

Comment: Paste the HTML on http://pastebin.com/ and share the link.

Comment: Is your webserver maybe remapping bootstrap.css to the non-existing minified version?


There could be some behind the scenes re-routing going on?

Comment: Does your unminified bootstrap.css have `@import` statements at the top of it that import other bootstrap component CSS files? Also what @Smartik said.

Comment: Does your browser developer tools (like inspect/network/console tabs) show any errors (particularly 404's when trying to access CSS files) when you remove the files?

Comment: I'm using the bare minimum source files of Bootstrap, and this is the html

http://pastebin.com/gq8UgQw4

I copied the minified css back and the custom css will do the trick, but it's still kinda weird thing to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some `@import` statements in the stylesheet you are declaring in your HTML. That means that your stylesheet makes use of another stylesheet.